# How to get dates as in csv with write() function?

Tags: r, date, xts

After running a code in R, I get xts object see

[image]

Using  `write.table(myresult, "myresult.csv", sep=",")`, I get csv file with ascending numbers as row names in column A.

I wish Date, similar to the xts object, is displayed instead in column A. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a function that is aware of the index that xts and zoo objects have. For example, `write.zoo()`:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
x <- round(x*100)
write.zoo(head(x), sep = ",")
# "Index","Open","High","Low","Close"
# 2007-01-02,5004,5012,4995,5012
# 2007-01-03,5023,5042,5023,5040
# 2007-01-04,5042,5042,5026,5033
# 2007-01-05,5037,5037,5022,5033
# 2007-01-06,5024,5024,5011,5018
# 2007-01-07,5013,5022,4999,4999
```